# Creating a new creative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-ads-api

I'm struggling to create a new creative. The URL that I'm posting is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act_________/adgroups?max_bid=1&name=asdfadf&campaign_id=_________&targeting={"action_spec_friend":[{"action.type":"like","object":"adjfadf"},{"action.type":"post","object":"adjfadf"}],"countries":["US"]}&redownload=1&bid_type=1&creative={"action_spec":{"action.type":"like","object":"adjfadf"},"title":"asdfadf","type":25}
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize this format. In the documentation, there seems to be some distinction between when you use `-d` in cURL versus when you use `-F` and I think this may have to do with my problem.

I am able to create a campaign, with this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act________/adcampaigns?end_time=1339819200&daily_budget=10000&name=Test Campain 2&redownload=1&campaign_status=1
```

But I can't add a creative to it through the API.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> there seems to be some distinction between when you use -d in cURL versus when you use -F and I think this may have to do with my problem.

-d sends data as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, whereas -F sends it as *multipart/form-data*.

From your question I’m guessing that you’re not able to use cURL(?) – but I can’t find any info what kind of system/environment your developing under. Please update your question with that info, than maybe we’ll be able to figure out another way to assemble the right kind of request.